# Coded UI Test: Simulating Mouse Clicks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mouse, coded-ui-tests

Hey I am currently learning and trying to get a good handle on Coded UI Testing with Visual Studio 2012. When the test is being performed, the user's mouse is taken over by the system performing the test. Is it possible to send mouse clicks to controls or have them, in a way, press themselves? Or am I stuck giving control of the mouse to the system until the test ends?

Thank you.

Comment: I understand I still have complete control of the mouse but I have to fight with test instead of being able to perform separate actions while the UI Test happens in the background.

Comment: Coded UI take over the computer, Coded UI does the equivalent of using the mouse and the keyboard. What sort of separate actions do you want to do while the test runs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there are any better solutions since I'm not a professional developing coded ui tests. However, a possible solution for this is to run your test through a [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), this will allow you to control your mouse locally while the [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) will play the records without you actually needing to focus the window.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. Just wanted to get some confirmation. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Click really quickly!!

But yes, you would have to run your tests outside of your local machine. Check out Microsoft's Test Controller and Test agents to getting your tests to run on other machines/VM